# How to solve ODE Bernoulli type equation plus a constant?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I would like  to solve the following differential equation:

$ \frac{dX}{dt} = a X - b X^c + d$. Where $a,b,c,d$ are constants.

For $d=0$, this EDO is a Bernoulli equation,  $ \frac{dX}{dt} = a X - b X^c $.

In this case this equation  can be exactly solved using  $Z=X^{1-n}$ and it is easily
reduced as
$\frac{dZ}{dt}= (1-n)(aZ -b)$.

Here, the question is,  how this ODE can be solved for $d \neq 0$, I would like to have a close and analytical expression?.

What is the analytical transformation needed to solve it ?.

Using Mathematica:

```
ode = X'[t] - a*X[t] +  b* X[t]^c + d == 0;
DSolve[ode, X[t], t]
```

the output is

```
{{X[t] -> InverseFunction[
     Inactive[Integrate][1/(
       d - a K[1] + b K[1]^c), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][-t + C[1]]}}
```

Interesting solutions  and comments are welcome.

Comment: The solution for c = p/q (reduced rational) seems to be `Solve[-q RootSum[ d + b #1^p - a #1^q &, ( Log[-#1 + X[t]^(1/q)] #1^(q - p))/(-p b + q a #1^(q - p)) &] == -t + C[1], X[t]]`

Comment: thanks @Michael E2 ,  sure  It will be interesting to  explore  a general polynomial  solutions  using Mathematica  by  fixing some parameters under some considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ode $\frac{dx}{dt}=a x- b x^c$ is not Bernoulli. It is simply separable since $a,b$ are
constants. The same with $\frac{dx}{dt}=a x- b x^c+d$ is separable.

Bernoulli has the form $\frac{dx}{dt}=f_0(t) x + f_1(t) x^n$.

The reason why $x'=a x- b x^c$ gives explicit solution is because
the integral can be found when solving as separable. i.e. it becomes

\begin{align*} 
\frac{dx}{dt} &= a x- b x^c \\
\frac{dx}{a x- b x^c} &= dt  \\
\int{\frac{dx}{a x- b x^c} } &= \int dt  \\
-\frac{\log \left(b-a x^{1-c}\right)}{a (c-1)} &= t+c_0
\end{align*}

Which can be written explicitly for $x(t)$ by raising both side to the exponential as

\begin{align*} 
x(t)= \left(\frac{b-e^{-a c t-a c c_1+a t+a c_1}}{a}\right){}^{\frac{1}{1-c}}
\end{align*}

Now when adding $d$, it is still separable. But the problem is that now the
integral itself that shows up using the same steps above has no
analytical solution. That is why Mathematica gives the solution
as implicit.

\begin{align*} 
\frac{dx}{dt} &= a x- b x^c +d  \\
\frac{dx}{a x- b x^c +d} &= dt  \\
\int{\frac{dx}{a x- b x^c +d} } &= \int dt  \\
\int{\frac{dx}{a x- b x^c +d} } &= t+c_0  \\
\end{align*}

This is the difference. Compare

```
Integrate[1/(a*x - b*x^c), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[1/(a*x - b*x^c + d), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So what does Mathematica do now? It can't integrate the left side in order to finish the solution as the case without $d$. So it gives up and says the solution is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this is an implicit solution.

If you can figure how to solve $\int{\frac{dx}{a x- b x^c +d} }$ then you can do better than what Mathematica did above.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser , before I posted  this. I already got a  solution. but  I am looking  and interested  in  a general  integral solution  by   choosing some parameters  for example c=a/b non integer, a, b>0., but  I don't know  if   using Mathematica  is possible to  obtain an anaytical solution.

Comment: **for example c=a/b non integer, a, b>0** Why can't you just type `c = a/b;
ode = X'[t] - a*X[t] + b*X[t]^c + d == 0; DSolve[ode, X[t], t]` ?  Next, plugin in any values you want for $a,b$. The issue is the integration itself. The integral that results can or not be integrable. That is all.